Stop chunkById in laravel query
I want to stop the query chunk loop, is there a way to do that? My code
$limit = 1000;
$total = 0;

$query->chunkById(
    100,
    function ($items) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            // do something

            if ($total >= $limit) {
                // how to stop?
            }
            
            $total++;
        }
    }
);

I already followed many solutions i found in many sites but still not working.

I found the solution to my problem, just return false in the loop
if ($total >= $limit) {
   return false;
}


How about the following the code?
function ($items) use (&$total, &$limit) {

